# Add delay to start execution thread with ScheduledExecutorService object

Tags: java, multithreading, callable

I’m implementing a pool of thread to send multiple get snmp. I’m using the Callable objects:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(size);
final Map<String, Future< >> map = new HashMap<String, Future< >>();
for (final String key : groupMap.keySet()) {
    final ObjectCallable objectCallable = new ObjectCallable(par1, par2, par3);
    try {
         Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
           LOGGER.error("Error delay in the submit Callable" + e.getMessage());
            }
    final Future< > result = executor.submit(objectCallable);
}
```

I need to add an execution delay between threads. I added a sleep before submit, it is correct? Someone knows some other method?

Comment: "I need to add an execution delay between threads." Can you explain more precisely your need ?

Comment: I would start the all threads not at the same time but with a small delay. Ex T1 start time 0, t2 start time 0+delay, .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [schedule](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.util.concurrent.Callable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method of `ScheduledExecutorService` (and its overloads) accept a `delay` parameter that seems to exactly define what you are looking for, as in:

> delay - the time from now to delay execution

What you are doing instead in your example is to artificially sleep on the current executing thread prior to submitting your `Callable`s for execution (which you are doing by invoking [ExecutorService#submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29), thus not leveraging the specific methods of `ScheduledExecutorService`).

Comment: Hi Mena, thanks for your reply. It is possible to use ScheduledExecutorService ad to have different time to start the execution for every thread?

Comment: @ottis79 if you `schedule` each `Callable` with its own `delay` that would precisely do that, yes.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I will add a delay for each single thread.